# get the name of the of each field on a table sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, relational-database

I am trying to do a simple query but I can not get the desired results.

I have a table BATTLE with two references id's. what I want is to get in one row, the name of each hero based on other table HERO

### BATTLE

- id
- hero1_id
- hero2_id

### HERO

- id
- name

I am doing this query

```
SELECT 
  battle.character1_id as p1,
  character.name,
  battle.character2_id as p2,
  character.name
FROM 
 battle, 
 character 
WHERE 
 character.id in (character1_id, character2_id)
```

But I am getting two rows by battle. I know I am doing something wrong but I don't know what?

[image: result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join `battle` on the `hero` table twice, once for each here:

```
SELECT h1.id AS id1, h1.name AS name1, h2.id AS id2, h2.name AS name2
FROM   battle b
JOIN   hero h1 ON h1.id = b.hero1_id
JOIN   hero h2 ON h2.id = b.hero2_id
```

Comment: The right answer, but I would recommend `left join`, in case a battle has only one hero.